# Compare route name in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.2 and Blade templating, currently I am using this code to send the user to their own profile

```
href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => Auth::user()->username]) }}
```

This code is in an `@if` statement in blade, I was wondering how I would be able to check to make sure the user is on their own profile before I show them elements they should only be able to see on their own profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use check similar to this in your controller:

```
if (Auth::check()) // Checks if user authenticated
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id; // Gets user ID
    // Do some stuff
}

return view('profile', compact('profileInfo'));
```

In this case any user will see only he's own profile.

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense now